# unexplained delay after QProgressBar finish loading

Tags: c++, qt, qprogressbar

I have emit signal from a loop (which make some calculations) that triggers progress bar update which located on the main GUI, after the loop ends the progress bar updated to 100% (the progress bar become hidden when the process ends), but than there is a delay, the progress bar stays on 100% and sometimes the mouse changes to busy, and only after few seconds the progress bar become hidden (indicates me that the delay ends), there is nothing after that loop, so nothing I can thinks of can make this delay.

- I should note that if the loop calculations are light (meaning not a lots of calculations need to be done) there is no such delay.

The emit signal is inside a class in the logic layer, I have try something by including `<QtGui/QApplication>` into that class (which sounds to me not the right thing to do, as this is the logic layer so why it should need QtGui libraries, but I'm only testing something), I put the following code `qApp->processEvents();` inside the loop and now things seems to run smother, no busy mouse, but still there is a delay (the only thing different I can react with the GUI while this delay occurs, but there is no updated results until this delay ends).

Because of the test with the `processEvents()` I was thinking it's something related to threads, but if so how can I correct the delay behavior, of-course if anyone thinks it could be something else, please do tell.

Some sample code:

Logic layer class:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
...

processMethod(...)
{
    Loop(...)
    {
        qApp->processEvents();
        emit processBarSignle(value);
        ...some calculations...
    }
    emit processBarSignle(100);
}
```

View layer (MainWindow):

```
on_btn_nextProcess_clicked()
{
    m_ui->pBar_process->setVisible(true);
    LogicClass->processMethod(...);
    m_ui->pBar_process->setVisible(false);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
...

processMethod(...)
{
    Loop(...)
    {
        emit processBarSignle(value);
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
        ...some calculations...
    }
    emit processBarSignle(100);
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
}
```

`processEvents()` is a static method of [QCoreApplication](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents), like that it is sufficient to include only `QCoreApplication` which is part of the `QtCore` library.

In addition, you should add `processEvents()` after the progress bar has been updated, not before that.

Note that `processEvents()` does not return until every event in Qt's Event Queue has been processed. If there is e.g. a `Cancel` button, you will have to check if the user actually cancelled the operation each time you called `processEvents()`.
You can exclude user-specific events like mouse clicks / key presses by using

```
QCoreApplication::processEvents( QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents )
```

but that will not allow clicking anything (e.g. a Cancel Button) while the loop is active.

As a further note: It should be called "processBarSi **ng** le" ;-)

---

Clarification on threads etc:

Your whole loop, and any mouse clicks etc are executed in only one thread. If you call `emit()`, the `slot` which is connected to that `signal` is executed instantly (*unless the slot was actually in a different thread*). In the meantime, the loop does not continue!

When the slot has finished, your loop will continue. In my example this means `processEvents()` will get called. Now if your slot updated the progress bar or did anything else which caused a repaint, there will be a repaint event in the Event Queue and this repaint will now happen.
If you execute `processEvents()` before calling your slot, there would be no repaint event which could be processed at this point.

Once again, the loop does not continue until `processEvents()` is completely done. When all pending events were processed, the loop continues with your calculations.

Comment: There is still delay with your method (I thinks less delay, but hard to tell).

Answer (score 0):

In your code sample, there is actually only one thread.   When `on_btn_nextProcess_clicked()` is called, it shows the progress bar, then runs `processMethod()` in the same thread.  Ideally you want to separate your UI and Data Processing logic.

In intialization, create a separate `QThread`, start it, and move your LogicClass object to that thread by calling logicClassObject->moveToThread([your new thread]).  Then, turn `processMethod()` into a slot, create a `startProcessing()` signal in MainWindow and connect the two.  Finally, create a `processingDone()` slot in `MainWindow` and a `finishedProcessing()` slot in `LogicClass` and connect them. When this is all set up you can change your code to the following:

```
void LogicClass::processMethod(...)
{
    Loop(...)
    {
        emit processBarSignal(value);
        ...some calculations...
    }
    emit processingDone();
}

void MainWindow::on_btn_nextProcess_clicked()
{
    m_ui->pBar_process->setVisible(true);
    emit startProcessing(...);
}

void MainWindow::finishedProcessing()
{
    m_ui->pBar_process->setVisible(false);
}
```

Whenever you connect signals and slots from two separate threads, multithreading is taken care of automatically.  Emitting the signal in one thread causes an event to be qeued in the other which only calls the slot once the second thread regains control.

In this case, the UI thread will schedule an event in the processing thread to start processing.  The processing thread will then continually schedule progressBar value updates and finally schedule an event to turn off the progress bar when its done.  The two threads will run according to the OS thread scheduler and processing won't block UI.

Comment: Should I use the same method to separate UI and the QGraphicsView?

Comment: QGraphicsView is part of the UI and needs to be in the UI thread.  You'll get errors if you move it out.  What you'll want to move out of the UI thread is any heavy processing that needs to be done as a precondition for setting up the QGraphicsScene.

Comment: Btw, I recommend that you checkout Maya Posch's excellent discussion of ["How To Really, Truly Use QThreads"](http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/)